# how does Database.forDataSource work in slick?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am currently setting up a project that uses play slick with scala. From the docs I find that to get a session we should do

**val db = Database.forDataSource(dataSource: javax.sql.DataSource)**

So I followed the pattern and used this in every Repository layer.(A layer on top of model similar to a dao).
 I have couple of repositories and I have duplicated this line .

My question is , does this connect to database every time of have a common pool and we get the connection from this pool ?

Comment: What play version do you use?

Comment: Play version 2 and slick verion 3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From slick documentation :

> Using a DataSource
>   You can provide a DataSource object to forDataSource. If you got it from the connection pool of your application framework, this plugs the pool into Slick.

```
val db = Database.forDataSource(dataSource: javax.sql.DataSource)
```

> When you later create a Session, a connection is acquired from the pool and when the Session is closed it is returned to the pool.

Comment: So  in another Repository , if I do val db = Database.forDataSource(dataSource: javax.sql.DataSource) , Does this creates a new pool of connections ?

Comment: The pooling is a part of Datasource : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html